# How to block all input on iPhone app(for jailbroken devices)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, jailbreak

I'm trying to block all user input in my app. That includes touch event,sleep button, home button, etc. It's for jailbroken device. So you can use whatever that works.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Press and hold the power button.

Answer (score 2):

Even with a Jailbroken device I dont think there  is anyway to prevent the home button from quitting your app.  Its a bit like ctrl-alt-delete on windows.

Comment: The hardware buttons are direct interrupts, short of patching the kernel or baseband it isn't possible to disable them, and even that may not be possible depending on how the HW is configured.

Answer (score 1):

Erm, how is this a good idea? There's no way they'd be able to exit the app then.

It's a bad form to ask for help creating what sounds like a malicious app, or at least not provide enough details to make it clear what the heck you're doing.